# html multiple select statements not working

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli

I have a form for adding events to each of my database tables.

In order for the data and time to be right I am using dropdown menus. However I am using 5 2 for the time and 3 for the date. In dream weaver on the second select statement it is highlighting it in yellow like I have an error. http://pastebin.com/NJB84hed

I would like to make sure this is also saving the id so that, the id can be posted in that table

```
$results=mysqli_query($con, "select * from Users where `userName` ='$username'");
    $id = 'id_cust';
```

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** You are missing a closing bracket `}` for your `if(isset($_POST['insert'])){`

```
if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
$artist = $_POST['artist'];
$place = $_POST['place'];
$hour = $_POST['hour'];
$minute = $_POST['min'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$open = $_POST['open'];
$time = $hour.':'.$minute;
$date = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day;
$result=mysqli_query($con,"insert into Concert values('$id','$artist','$date','$time','$place','$price','$open')");
                if($result)
                {
                echo 'Values updated successfully';
                }
?>
```

Should be

```
if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
$artist = $_POST['artist'];
$place = $_POST['place'];
$hour = $_POST['hour'];
$minute = $_POST['min'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$open = $_POST['open'];
$time = $hour.':'.$minute;
$date = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day;
$result=mysqli_query($con,"insert into Concert values('$id','$artist','$date','$time','$place','$price','$open')");
                if($result)
                {
                echo 'Values updated successfully';
                }
} // MISSING THIS CLOSING BRACKET
?>
```

**(2)** On line 73 you misspelled your select closing tag

```
</selct>
```

should be

```
</select>
```

**(3)** Also, I assume

```
$results=mysqli_query($con, "select * from Users where `userName` ='$username'");
$id = 'id_cust';
```

should be something like

```
$results=mysqli_query($con, "select * from Users where `userName` ='$username'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$id = $row['id_cust'];
```

Comment: thank you, it is always good to have another pair of eyes for problems that fixed it

Comment: happy to help. make sure to mark as answered (as well as any of the other questions that you have asked that are still without a selected answer) http://stackoverflow.com/about